# how to handle login window in tab view controller when user is already logged in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have an app where there are 5 tabs.

I have third tab as Login. Here I call LoginViewController.

What I want to do is if user is already logged in, I want to show user MyAccountViewController instead of LoginViewController.

For that I am using below.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"isLoggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
        MyAccountViewController *secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyAccount"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:NO];
    }
}
```

However calling in DidAppear is too late.

Also if I double tap on Login tab, it shows Login first and after some delay show MyAccount.

What I want is if I am logged in, MyAccount will be root and when not logged in Login will be root.

Any idea how to get this done?

---

### Edit 1

I tried as below but gives BAD_EXCESS

```
MyAccountViewController *tabViewC22 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyAccount"];

MainViewController *tabViewC0 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
AboutUsViewController *tabViewC1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutUs"];
LoginViewController *tabViewC21 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
LocationViewController *tabViewC3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Location"];
AboutUsViewController *tabViewC4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutUs"];


if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"isLoggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
{
    myViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tabViewC0, tabViewC1, tabViewC22,tabViewC3,tabViewC4, nil];
}
else
{
    myViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tabViewC0, tabViewC1, tabViewC21,tabViewC3,tabViewC4, nil];
}

//set the view controllers for the tab bar controller
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:myViewControllers];
```

Comment: Why don't you check it in app delegate.
I f user is logged in directly open you view controller else if not logged in open Login view controller tab

Comment: @Chetan : **Login** tab is third tab and not first tab... How can I decide that in appdelegate? I do what you are saying when app is non-tabbed...

Comment: You can open any tab. Initialise your tab bar first then check for login and write the selected index as required

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = Tab_Index;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the check while you are initializing the tab-bar view controller items

```
 NSArray *myViewControllers = nil;

 if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"isLoggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
 {

   myViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                   self.myAccountViewController,
                                   self.secondViewController, nil];
 }       
 else
 {
   myViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                   self.loginViewController,
                                   self.secondViewController, nil];

 }  

//set the view controllers for the tab bar controller
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:myViewControllers];
```

Comment: You have to write this, where you are initializing the tab-bar view controller

Comment: see my updated question... I have posted what I tried, but gives BAD_EXCESS

Comment: In which line, getting the BAD_EXCESS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using it the right way however it is not that wrong, but what i found a bit out of place was pushing "MyAccountViewController" if login is found, which is obvious case meaning the user would not log out from the app so frequently.

I have logged in facebook since 4 months and till now i haven't logged out. If the user is not logged in you can push or present the login view controller instead.

So in every case MyAccount would be your third view controller but a check in viewWillAppear will rectify your problem.

Try setting `[tabbarController setSelectedIndex:2];`

The thing I wanted to convey was a bit lengthy so I couldn't put this in comment